# how to find multiple locations using google maps api

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.forms, google-maps-markers

I want to know if I can look for multiple locations using the google maps api. For example, I want to find restaurants and museums using one url 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Manhattan&key=", so I can use the same JSON file instead of duplicating files

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.753,-122.443&radius=1000&type=library&key={YourKey}

This will return all libraries within 1000 meters radius in SF.

Set your `location` parameter: be it a Lat-Lng or address.

Then set `radius` parameter: 1 = 1 meter.

Assign `type` parameter: to restaurant. [More on Type](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types)

Then you will get your JSON data for your restaurants. Then make other request for other type. Can't have more than one type. [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). Making more than one HTTP request still counts towards your daily quota, fyi.

Comment: +1 this is the way to do it when you know where you're looking and what you're looking for. The text search API is meant for searching for user input. Even then though you can specify a location and constraint, `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=user%20input&location=37.78,-122.42&radius=7500&key=apikey` (we search SF too :)

Comment: Also the [Radar search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests) can be useful for this type of query - but it's being deprecated in June 2018. Boo.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you search for *"restaurants or museums in sundancesquare"* your query is interpreted as *"restaurants museums sundancequare"* as in my experience the maps API doesn't parse your query for meaning, it just grabs the search terms out of it, and ignores directional words like "in".

It's very difficult to predict what results you would get - you might only get matches that match restaurant **and** museum **and** sundancesquare, you might get a mix of the two, and you might get something else you're not expecting: there's no guarantee with this call whether the results will actually *be* restaurants or museums, you might get restaurant supplies or restaurant insurance or anything that matches the term.

You should be specifying the type and using a nearby search as in [@MRestine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310517/43846).

However you still can't search for two types, as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) says:

> Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. **Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored).**

I don't really understand your question, though. You say you want to do this *"so I can use the same JSON file instead of duplicating files"* - why are you using files for this? And even if you must, can't you parameterise them so you can change the query?